# Recovering a Windows XP machine broken by trying to install pcANYWHERE 8.0

Tags: windows, windows-xp, uninstall, restore, pcanywhere

I tried installing pcANYWHERE 8.0 on a Windows XP machine, ignoring the compatibility warning dialog, on the assumption that the client would still be usable for connecting to Windows 9x machines and older.

Now Windows XP gets stuck on a black 640x480 screen when booting, even in safe mode. What's the procedure for getting rid of it if the system won't boot far enough to get to Add/Remove Programs?

Comment: Easy! Recover using last disk image.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik You might have noticed that I posted both the ask and the answer and did it simultaneously using the "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" checkbox in the "Ask Question" form. I posted this here after already having solved my own problem because I couldn't find any mention of this online aside from one passing (and quite vague) mention that someone else ran into the problem and resorted to reinstalling the whole machine, Super User has better SEO than my blog, and I want to make sure others who might run into it can find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Choose "Last Know Good Configuration (your most recent settings that worked)" instead of "Safe Mode" in the F8 menu.
2. If you're expecting auto-login and get an enterprise-style login dialog, just hitting Enter to use the pre-filled username and no password should work. (Apparently pcANYWHERE causes this and it happens with compatible versions too.)
3. Once the system has successfully started, go to Add/Remove Programs and remove pcANYWHERE32.
4. To play it safe, go to Start > Programs > Accessories > System Tools > System Restore and rewind your settings to the most recent system restore point.

Comment: why did someone -1 this?  You could at least leave a comment so the poster knows why it wasn't helpful.  I'm giving you your -1 back for this reason.